# Format Date Time in C#

Tags: c#, formatting, date-formatting

I just wanted to change one string of date to DateTime.

However when I try to print, it always said that the result is `5/31/2009`**`8:00:00 AM`**

Any idea why this thing happens?

```
namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Parse("5/31/2009 12:00:00 AM" );
        }

        static readonly string ShortFormat = "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

        static readonly string[] Formats = { ShortFormat };

        static void Parse(string text)
        {
            // Adjust styles as per requirements
            DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(text, ShortFormat,
                                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you would need `M/dd/yyyy` notice date is two digits

Comment: Nobody answering seems to have noticed that the output is 4 hours off the input.

Comment: What is your timezone? The code you wrote assumes UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DateTimeStyles.None` or `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` if you want the `DateTime` parsed to not take account of timezones:

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(text, ShortFormat,
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      DateTimeStyles.None);
```

When you use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` an automatic timezone conversion occurs against the computer timezone.

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx):

> AssumeUniversal - If no time zone is specified in the parsed string, the string is assumed to denote a UTC.

Comment: no idea who the downvoter is, but it's a shame the only answer that's properly read the question is downvoted! (+1 from me, btw.)

Comment: Sure an accepted answer is better than the first answer ... lol

Comment: @hamad - Of course it is. Especially if the first answer doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to write `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` for the date format.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print a `DateTime` in a specified format you need to use the `ToString` method.  Like so.

```
result.ToString("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

The second parameter (`format`) defines the format that the string (`S`) must be in for it to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

All the DateTime formats are described [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). You should instead use

```
static readonly string ShortFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
```

Comment: If you're going to point somebody to documentation, at least point them to **the** documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Change shortformat to

```
static readonly string ShortFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
```

Your string stand for this

```
"05/31/2009 12:00:00 AM"
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

Number on top corresponds to format below

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your time zone, and I think your time zone is GMT+4 not GMT-4 as bukko answered.
Anyway, just use:

```
DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal
```

instead of:

```
DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal
```